# Ansible debug loop output as a single list?

Tags: debugging, module, ansible

I have the following debug task, which lists the image and version attributes of {{image_names}}.

```
---
- name: "List Images"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.image }}:{{ item.version }}"
  loop: "{{ image_names }}"
```

The looped variable looks something like this

```
  image_names:
  - { service_name: "xxxxxxx",             registry: "xxxxxxx", image: "xxxxxxx",             version: "xxxxxxx" }
  - { service_name: "xxxxxxx",             registry: "xxxxxxx", image: "xxxxxxx",             version: "xxxxxxx" }
...
```

The output I receive on ansible tower is

```
ok: [host] => (item={u'service_name': u'xxxxxxx', u'image': u'xxxxxxx', u'version': u'xxxxxxx', u'registry': u'xxxxxxx'}) => {
    "msg": "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
ok: [host] => (item={u'service_name': u'xxxxxxx', u'image': u'xxxxxxx', u'version': u'xxxxxxx', u'registry': u'xxxxxxx'}) => {
    "msg": "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
ok: [host] => (item={u'service_name': u'xxxxxxx', u'image': u'xxxxxxx', u'version': u'xxxxxxx', u'registry': u'xxxxxxx'}) => {
    "msg": "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
```

Is there a way to join all of the "msg:" outputs into one list so it looks like

```
msg: 
 - "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
 - "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
 - "xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ image_names|
                 json_query('[].[image, version]')|
                 map('join', ':') }}"
      vars:
        image_names:
          - {service_name: x1, registry: x2, image: x3, version: x4}
          - {service_name: y1, registry: y2, image: y3, version: y4}
          - {service_name: z1, registry: z2, image: z3, version: z4}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - x3:x4
  - y3:y4
  - z3:z4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option as of [Ansible 2.5](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/use-ansibles-yaml-callback-plugin-better-cli-experience) is using yaml for your callback instead of the default skippy. Change the following two options in your ansible.cfg:

```
# Use the YAML callback plugin.
stdout_callback = yaml
# Use the stdout_callback when running ad-hoc commands.
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

This changes stdout for debug messages from a giant single line:

```
fatal: [vulnmanager]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 99, "stderr": "Shared connection to <FQDN>.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to <FQDN> closed."], "stdout": "\r\nRHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-export-libs-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64\r\nRHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-libs-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64\r\nRHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-libs-lite-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64\r\nRHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-license-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.noarch\r\nRHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-utils-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64\r\nRHSA-2021:2168              Important/Sec. bpftool-4.18.0-305.3.1.el8_4.x86_64\r\nRHSA-2021:1578     There are 44 available for installation on <FQDN>
```

to a yaml-based, much more readable version:

```
fatal: [vulnmanager]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 99
  stderr: |-
    Shared connection to <FQDN> closed.
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: |2-
  
    RHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-export-libs-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64
    RHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-libs-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64
    RHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-libs-lite-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64
    RHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-license-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.noarch
    RHSA-2021:1989              Important/Sec. bind-utils-32:9.11.26-4.el8_4.x86_64
    RHSA-2021:2168              Important/Sec. bpftool-4.18.0-305.3.1.el8_4.x86_64
    RHSA-2021:1578              Important/Sec. bpftool-4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64
There are 44 available for installation on <FQDN>
```